# Store component in an object in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**I am trying to store a component as an object value so that I can use it for a slider element**

*in the declaration component*

```
const dataSlider = [
  {button: `${<Button className='w-full btn-secondary' title='Use this environment instead' />}`},
  {button: `${<ButtonGeneral width='w- 40' title='Selected' />}`}

]

<Slider dataSlider={dataSlider} />
```

*in the component where I want to use it*

```
const Slider = ({dataSlider}) => {
  return (
    {dataSlider.map(obj => {
       <div>
        {obj.button}
       </div>
      }
    }
  )
}
```

*But in the output it show like this*

[image]

How can show the button component in the slider?

Comment: You have to return from a `map`. `dataSlider.map(obj => { return (<div>...)})`

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `${}` like this:

```
button: <Button className="w-full btn-secondary" title="Use this environment instead" />,
```

And need to return inside map:

```
{dataSlider.map(obj => (
  <div>
   {obj.button}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: It worked bro, thanks very much, but I can't upvote it as my reputation is too low yet

Answer (score 1):

The `${}` syntax is string interpolation. It takes the things inside the curly braces and turns them into a string, then combines them with the rest of the string. React components are objects, not strings. Get rid of the tics, the dollar sign and the curly braces.

Your final structure should look like this:

```
const dataSlider = [
  {
    button: <Button 
      className='w-full btn-secondary'
      title='Use this environment instead'
    />
   },
   {
     button: <ButtonGeneral
       width='w- 40' 
       title='Selected'
     />
   }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the component instance instead of converting it to a string by using string intrapolation

```
const dataSlider = [
  {button: <Button className='w-full btn-secondary' title='Use this environment instead' />},
  {button: <ButtonGeneral width='w- 40' title='Selected' />}

]

<Slider dataSlider={dataSlider} />
```

Comment: Glad to have helped